Kid holds barbed wire to save his parents
All I can remember about this action movie from the 90s is a kind of sadistic torture in which a couple is hanging over a well. The only way their child has to save them from falling inside is holding or pulling the barbed wire with which they are tied.
The bad guys who did set this situation up are observing. And maybe laughing or enjoying.
This happens in an outside location. They are on a desert or a sand ground. 
It could be a childhood memory that explains the protagonist's adult personality.
I would say it is an american film. Its atmosphere could match Chuck Norris' style.

Sounds like Cyborg with Jean-Claude Van Damme from 1989 but I think you got some details a bit wrong (it's a girl, for one). From the synopsis of one of the scenes:

While hanging from the mast, [hero] Gibson flashes back for the last time to his adopted family in the country. He and the oldest girl and her little brother are tied up with barbwire hanging over a well. Fender gives the barbwire to the younger sister Haley (Haley Peterson) and tells her if she can hold it, her family will live. The wire rips through her hands and the family falls into the well. Gibson manages to climb out of the well, but the girl and her brother have died.

You can see the scene here around the 4 minute mark [WARNING: GRAPHIC]:




Fast and accurate! It's interesting how I did rewrite the scene in my mind to my taste or fears, and how I totally forgot the mast part of the scene :) Thanks
